# Enable UFW noninteractively (-y failed)

Tags: command-line, firewall, ufw

How to enable `ufw` noninteractively?

`sudo enable ufw -y` does not achieve that. The -y is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

`sudo ufw --force enable`

or

`echo "y" | sudo ufw enable`